# Parse a String for image src

Tags: javascript, string, image

I have a String like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/imgres" ><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhUUEhQUFRQVFRQVFRQVFBQVFxQUFRUXFhQUFBUYHCggGBolHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFBAQGiwkHyQsLCwsLCwtLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLP" /></a>
```

now I want to extract the src content between the quotation marks. How cann I do that

Comment: don't downvote everyone's answer if it's not the one you were looking for.

Comment: Is the data something that you're comfortable handing to the browser's builtin HTML parser or might it be untrustworthy?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest not using regex and simply using DOM approaches:

```
function retrieveProp(htmlString, from, prop) {
    var tmp = document.createElement('div');
    tmp.innerHTML = htmlString;
    var elem = tmp.getElementsByTagName(from)[0];
    return elem[prop];
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b4hEj/).

Comment: An interesting number of down-votes to the answers for this question: would anyone care to explain/guess why?

Comment: I don't know who is doing it. Yours is the only solution that works, but isn't slow to always create elements?

Comment: It depends on what you're comparing it to; if there's a faster way, then yes it is; if the alternative is 'not working' then no, it isn't.

Comment: @kaputu: I think this method would throw exception if no img is found because of [0].

Comment: @KhanhTo: well, yes; but why would the OP be looking for a property of an object/element that doesn't exist in the string in the first place? And this can be addressed with a slight revision: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/b4hEj/6/

Comment: @DavidThomas: good code should not expect input to be always valid. well, I need to go to sleep now.

Answer (score 2):

First, set `id` for your `img`:

```
<a href="http://www.google.de/imgres" ><img id="your_image_id" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhUUEhQUFRQVFRQVFRQVFBQVFxQUFRUXFhQUFBUYHCggGBolHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFBAQGiwkHyQsLCwsLCwtLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLP" /></a>
```

Then use the following:

```
var src = document.getElementById("your_image_id").attr('src');
```

Also I advice you to check [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) in DOM specification.

If you can't set `id` for it as you say - than you are probably taking all links from webpage with some kind of selection (e.g. selecting by class using JQuery), so the solution could be like this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var src = $(this).children('img').src; // here is your string
});
```

Comment: no I get the data from the Web I cannot give it an id

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery, you can do it like this.

```
function extract(data,tag,attribute){
    var html = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");
    return html.find(tag).attr(attribute);
}
```

where tag in your case is "img", and attribute is "src".

```
var html = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");
```

Wrap the string inside a div to ensure there is always a root node. [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AkqwS/1/)

In case you want to extract all the "src" and return an array, try this

```
  function extract(data,tag,attribute){
        var html = $("<div>" + data + "</div>");
        var returnedData = [];
        html.find(tag).each(function(){
             returnedData.push($(this).attr(attribute));
        });
        return returnedData;
    }
```

Comment: no I get the data from the Web I cannot give it an id

Comment: @kaputu, check out my updated answer with demo and another case when you want to extract all the src (if there are many img tags)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the way you want to do this.

If it's a string, you could use a regular expression:

```
/.*src=\"(.*?)\".*/.exec('<a href="http://www.google.de/imgres" ><img id="image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxQTEhUUEhQUFRQVFRQVFRQVFBQVFxQUFRUXFhQUFBUYHCggGBolHBQUITEhJSkrLi4uFx8zODMsNygtLisBCgoKDg0OFBAQGiwkHyQsLCwsLCwtLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLP" /></a>')
```

The best way though would be through the DOM. Give it an ID and get the 'src' attribute.

```
<img src=".." id="img" />
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('img').src
```

**Edit**
I now see that you can't set an ID, as mentioned by others you could loop through every img tag.

Native:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
{
     var src = imgs[i].src
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('img').each(function ()
{
     var src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Comment: thanks but the regex does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/b4hEj/2/

Comment: Look at the quotes. I updated my regex with double quotes, you're jsfiddle is still using single quotes. so **/.*src=\"** instead of **/.*src=\'**